# rsync adding extra directory to command

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm scripting an rsync command, and currently I am trying to do something like...

```
rsync -av -e ssh $DATASTORE/usr/local/somepath $DESTDIR/usr/local/someotherpath/
```

if I echo $DATASTORE it shows

```
echo $DATASTORE
username@remotehost.net
```

If I run the command I get

```
/vagrant/username@remotehost.net/usr/local/somepath no suck file or diectory
```

I don't quite understand, why its adding /vagrant in there (/vagrant is the current directory I am in), and where this has come from ? I'm guessing I can't quite do it like that, but I'd like to understand what its doing and how I can get around it (if safe) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need to separate the host specification from the path specification with a colon (`:`) -

```
rsync -av -e ssh "$DATASTORE":/usr/local/somepath "$DESTDIR"/usr/local/someotherpath/
```

I will also point out that this will put `somepath` into your target directory `"$DESTDIR"/usr/local/someotherpath`, so that you end up with `"$DESTDIR"/usr/local/someotherpath/somepath`. If this is not desired behaviour, but you want the *contents* of `somepath` in your target `someotherpath` directory, append a slash to the source path:

```
rsync -av -e ssh "$DATASTORE":/usr/local/somepath/ "$DESTDIR"/usr/local/someotherpath/
```

Comment: All answers good thanks, can't believe I missed the colon, long day! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
$DATASTORE
```

by

```
${DATASTORE}:
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing everything fine. Just missing a colon here. Try this:

```
rsync -av -e ssh $DATASTORE:/usr/local/somepath $DESTDIR/usr/local/someotherpath/
```